# How to migrate all database from INNODB to MARIADB?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am new for this task. I have no idea that how to so this?
So please help me with explanation so that I can do it by myself.

Answer (score 2):

InnoDB is an MySQL/MariaDb Storage Engine. So if you have a SQL backup from your DBs you a easy change to MariaDB. MAriaDB is binary replacement.

To Change from MySQL to MariaDB is easy.
- Backup your Data with mysqldump
- uninstall MySQL
- install MariaDB

Here ist a Link for the Install : https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/#mirror=host-europe

Comment: But How to do it? What are the steps for it?

Comment: i have change my answer